# Converting div animation code to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

In my project I need to animate some element, change its height with animation and I'm not allowed to use `jQuery`. I'm having hard time converting the following code (only the animation part) to vanilla js:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sn93nqch/)

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#div").height(20).animate({
    height: 50
  }, 200);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla JS doesn't have any animation routines. To do this you'll need to write your own timers to update the properties of the element at the required intervals.

However a better alternative would be to do the animation in CSS and use JS to simply add a class to the element which triggers the animation, something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('div').classList.add('foo');
})
```

```css
#div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: height 0.2s;
}
#div.foo {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<button id="button">animate height</button>
```

Note the `transition` rule on the `#div` is what is doing the animation magic here.